# Find a basis and state its dimension of a $C$-vector space polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

The  $C$ vector space $V$  of polynomials $P(t) \in C[t]$ of degree at most $n$ and such that 
$P(a) = P'(a) = 0$ for $a \in C$ fixed. Indication : prove that $P(t) \in  V \Leftrightarrow (t − a)^2$ divides $P(t)$.

So i really have no idea where the $(t-a)^2$ comes in. :/

And the mark scheme says:
Let $P(t) \in C[t]$. If  $P(t)$ can be divided by $(t−a)^2$, its clear that $P(a) = P'(a) = 0$. 
Reciprocally if $P(a) = P'(a) = 0$, then  $P(t)$ can be divided by $(t − a)$ and we can write 
$P(t) = (t − a)Q(t)$.

We derive: $P'(t) = (t − a)'Q(t) + (t − a)Q'(t) = Q(t) + (t − a)Q'(t)$.
The hypothesis $P'(a) = 0$ implies then that $Q(a) = 0$, so  $Q(t)$ is divided by $(t-a)$ and finally
$P(t) = (t − a)Q(t) = ((t − a)^2)Q_1(t)$. $\forall P(t) \in V$ , $P(t) = ((t − a)^2)Q_1(t)$, with $\deg (Q_1) \leq n − 2$, therefore a basis of $V$ is $\lbrace((t − a)^2)t^j,  j = 0, . . . , n − 2\rbrace$ of dimension $n − 1$.

I fail to comprehend the mark scheme. Where does the square come in?

Comment: You can also use the Taylor formula

Comment: I'm not sure where your problem is?

Comment: @snulty like why do we divide by (t-a)^2. And the mark scheme is very vague in my opinion. Maybe i just dont get polynomials but i dont understand the answer at all.I wanted someone to explain it in their own words but with the same notation as the mark scheme